# powershell filter to remove .pdf extension in the name of a file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use powershell to get all child elements in a folder the code I am using is

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\clntfiles
```

this code gives output like

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
-a---         4/29/2015   9:11 AM    6919044 HD 100616 Dec2014.pdf  
-a---          5/1/2015  11:42 AM    7091019 HD 101642 Jan2015.pdf
```

I don't want Mode lastWriteTime Length and name of file without .pdf extension

the output should be like

```
Dec2014
Jan2015
```

I am not sure how to filter that. please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by posting something similar to Leptonator's answer, but simplified by using the `Select-Object` command (alias `Select` used in code because it's habit, and I'm lazy).

```psh
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\clntfiles | Select -ExpandProperty BaseName
```

Now that gets you the file names without extension. But, you actually asked for only part of the file names, as the first file name is "HD 100616 Dec2014.pdf" and you specified that you actually only want "Dec2014" to be returned. We can do that a couple different ways, but my favorite of them would be a RegEx match (because RegEx is awesome, and I think the `LastIndexOf`/`SubString` combo is overly complicated imho).

So, a RegEx match of `"\w+$"` will get what you want. That is broken down like this:

`\w` means any letter or number
`+` means 1 or more of them
`$` means the end of the string/line

So that's 1 or more alpha-numeric characters at the end of the string. We pipe our array of file names into a `ForEach-Object` loop (alias `ForEach` used out of habit), and then we have:

```psh
$Files | ForEach{ [RegEx]::Matches($_,"\w+$")}
```

Now, this outputs a `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]` object, which is more than you want, but it does have a property `Value` which is exactly what you asked for! So we use `Select -Expand` again for that property and the output is precisely what you asked for:

```psh
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\clntfiles | Select -ExpandProperty BaseName
$files | ForEach{[regex]::Matches($_,"\w+$")} | Select -Expand Value
```

RegEx matches are really handy, and if you learn about them you can simplify that quite a bit more like this:

```psh
gci C:\clntfiles -Rec | ?{$_.BaseName -match "(\w+)$"} | %{$Matches[1]}
```

That one line, as well as the two line code above it both should output:

```psh
Dec2014
Jan2015
```

Comment: I'm assuming this occured to you as well `gci C:\clntfiles -Rec | %{($_.BaseName -split '\s+')[-1]}`

Comment: Nope, I always forget that you can use a RegEx match for the `-split` method. Good point @Matt

Comment: You could probably safely use the split method as well with a regular space as some might be more comfortable with a non-regex solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it for you..

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\clntfiles

if ($files -ne $null)
{
    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        $file.BaseName
    }
}
```

In my folder, it shows:

```
> 2014-03-28_exeresult_file
> 2014-03-30_exeresult_file
> 2014-03-31_exeresult_file
> 2014-04-02_exeresult_file
> 2014-04-03_exeresult_file
> 2014-04-04_exeresult_file
> 2014-04-06_exeresult_file
> 2014-04-08_exeresult_file
```

and are indeed .txt files
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -name -path C:\clntfiles`. This will get you only the file names.

Working solution:

```
$names = Get-ChildItem -name
foreach($n in $names) {$n.Substring(0,$n.IndexOf("."))}
```

You can also use `LastIndexOf` if part of the file name is `.`

Comment: He only wants the names and not the extensions.